# Minimizing a bivariate quartic

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following question.

> Consider the function $$f(x,y) = 8xy +\dfrac14(x-y)^{4}$$
>
> (a) find all the local minimum points of $f$ on $\mathbb R^2~$.
>
> (b) Does $~f~$ have any global minimum point on $\mathbb R^2~$?
>
> Justify your answer rigorously.

For part (a), I obtained two local minimum, which are attained at $~(1,-1)~$ and $~(-1,1)~$.

However, I have no idea how to show that there is no global minimum point on $\mathbb R^2$.

Is it related to the connect of strictly convex of $f$ over $\mathbb R^2$?

If so, how can I proof there is/ is no global minimum point on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: What value does f have at those minima? Can f be smaller than either value somewhere else?

Comment: in both minima, f has a value of (-4). for your second question, I think this is the smallest value as I obtained then as local minimum point by undergoing Hessian Matrix of the 2nd partial derivatives of $~f~$

Comment: How do you know $f$ is convex?

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable changes

$$x=u+v, \>\>\> \>\>y = u-v$$

to reexpress the function as,

$$f(u,v) = 8(u^2-v^2)+4v^4 = 8u^2 + 4(v^2-1)^2 -4 \ge -4$$

Thus, -4 is the absolute minimum value that $f(x,y)$ takes, hence the global minima.

The above global minima are at $u=0$ and $v^2=1$, which in the original $x$ and $y$ coordinates are at the points (1,-1) and (-1,1). So, for this function, the local minima are also the global ones.